# Is it possible to get a context in a CompositionLocalProvider?

Tags: android, json, android-jetpack-compose

I've got some configuration in a json file stored at the asset folder of the app.
I need this configuration during my complete app so I thought a CompositionLocalProvider may be a good choice.

But now I realize I need the context for parsing that json file and that doesn't seem to be possible.

Might there be another way to achieve the goal I'm looking for?

This is my implementation so far:

```
val LocalAppConfiguration = compositionLocalOf {
    Configuration.init(LocalContext.current) // <-- not possible
}
```

Where my Configuration is like:

```
object Configuration {

    lateinit var branding: Branding

    fun init(context: Context) {
        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        branding = gson.fromJson(
            InputStreamReader(context.assets.open("branding.json")),
            Branding::class.java
        )
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compositionLocalOf` is not a `Composable` function. So, `LocalContext.current` can not be used.

I believe you can achieve the similar goal if you  move the initialization of `branding` outside of the default factory. You'd then do the initialization inside your actual composable where you have access to Context.

Here's a sample code to explain what I'm talking about.

```
val LocalAppConfiguration = compositionLocalOf {
    Configuration
}
```

```
@Composable
fun RootApp(
    isDarkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val brandedConfiguration = Configuration.init(LocalContext.current)
    MaterialTheme {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalAppConfiguration provides brandedConfiguration) {
            //your app screen composable here.
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you will also have to modify your `init` method slightly.

```
object Configuration {

    lateinit var branding: Branding

    fun init(context: Context) : Configuration {
        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        branding = gson.fromJson(
            InputStreamReader(context.assets.open("branding.json")),
            Branding::class.java
        )
        return this
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an approach I came up with after I wrote the post :)
I haven't checked it out yet, but I'll reply tomorrow to see if it worked.

Thanks!

Comment: It work's as intended